# Unable to start my linux (cent OS ) machine in run level 5

Tags: linux

Suddenly my machine not working under run level 5 and it seems to be problem with xserver and it is saying that "in last 90 seconds xserver restarted 6 times and unable to start" and then just giving blank screen.So i changed the run level to 3 and using startx command i am managing to work now.can any one help me on this.......?

Answer (score 1):

Check /var/log/Xorg* where xorg writes the reason of failure

Comment: log is there but i am unable to understand the issue...... it is saying "Could not init font path element unix/:7100, removing from list!"

Comment: Check this out: http://linuxgazette.net/93/yuan.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your disk-space. You might have inadvertently run out of free space on one of your partitions - particularly the one holding /tmp and /home.

Comment: space is not a problem...... it has enough space ......i verified it....